# How many web servers will I be able to run with a dual core processor?

Tags: memory, cpu, virtualization

This question is simple, do I need to have as many virtual machines as cores I have, or can I have more?

I plan to use my current PC as server, it is a Core 2 Duo E8400 @ 3.0, 4gb DDR2 (could buy 4 more), and 500GB sata disk.

I will host some web servers for me, for testing and perhaps some "home made" production servers.

I will use only linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a very difficult one to answer.  We don't know which linux, which web server, which modules, which (if any) database service, how many sites, how many concurrent users, how intensively used the site will be by an average user, whether there will be statistics and reporting processes (eg analytice) running in the background, whether its static or dynamic content, which content managers, how graphics/media intensive, whether there are any "live elements" (chat rooms, java apps), how fast the disk you mentioned is, what speed the RAM is clocked at, how fast your internet connection is...

The list of unknowns can go on forever!  Because of this, we are unable to give a real estimate of how many sites/services you could offer from this disk.

The only real advice is to start with 1 ro 2 and then build it up until you start to see a congestion problem - at which point, add more hardware, additional servers or a better net connection.

A word of advice though - the speed of the disk will have a massive impact on the speed of a web server.  When doing DB lookups, the amount of data sent to teh browser is usually small - but the amount of data "sifted" through on the drives can be massive!  Likewise, when seeking and loading images, web page files etc - the slowest component of most machines is the drive and a server can only truely operate as fast as its slowest component.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me valuable advices. My goal is to have some low access sites, and if they get bigger, then move to some dedicated servers, but I want to try and test how I can operate with different servers, that is, for example, having dedicated SQL servers, load balancing, etc, and since I will have only 1 machine I wanted to know how many ubuntu servers will I be able to run to test these interactions, I mean, how many resource intensive is operating system only.